# Expectation of the supremum of some indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\{X_n\}$ be some sequence of positive random variables.
Then what is
$$
  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\theta} \mathbb{1}\left\{ \frac{n-1}{n} \theta \le X_n < \theta \right\} \right]?
$$

**What I have done.**

Since for each realization of $X_n$, we can set $\theta$ by $\frac{n}{n-1}X_n$, then we have
$$
  \sup_{\theta} \mathbb{1}\left\{ \frac{n-1}{n} \theta \le X_n < \theta \right\} = 1\qquad\text{a.s.}
$$
Thus, the limit value is $1$.
So am I right?

Comment: It is correct if $X_n > 0$. For $X_n<0$ it is not true that $X_n <\frac n {n-1} X_n$

Comment: oh, I added an constraint $X_n> 0$.